# jQuery clear button inside every text input field

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to use jQuery to dynamically add a clear button (an X) at the right of EVERY input field on the site. After having looked at some examples, all of these require me to change the actual input fields which I obviously can't do throughout the entire site.

Is there a simple jquery script I can use? A script to add a clear button to every input field of type "text". Regardless of class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extreme rough draft.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);

   $('<div class="clrInput"/>').css({
       position:'absolute',
       left: $this.offset().left + $this.width() + 10, //10 for extra spacing from edge
       top: $this.offset().top,
       width: $this.height(),
       height: $this.height()
   }).text(' X ').data('inputEQ', $this.index()).appendTo('body');
});
$(document).on('click', '.clrInput', function(){
    $('input[type=text]').eq($(this).data('inputEQ')).val('');
});
```

[And your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQaGM/)

**note**

To preserve performance, replace `document` with the closest static parent element.

Comment: I like this! Thanks! You get the answer in 7 minutes

Answer (score 3):

You can use the selector below.

```
var $inputs = $('input[type=text]')
```

That selects all the inputs of type text and then perform the logic.

If there is some internal logic the you want to perform which is different for each input, use a `$.each` to iterate over the inputs and perform the logic

```
$inputs.each(function() {

     // Perform your logic
});
```